How to add reverse-scroll in React while using react-virtualized with InfiniteLoader for loading messages?
I want to render the messages in a chat application in reverse order, with the most recent message at the bottom and the oldest message above it, and so on. infiniteLoader should load more chats when scrolled up it should be rendered from bottom to top and infinite loading of messages should also be from bottom to top.
Can anyone tell me the basic implementaion or an example in React JS.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
